# Defining fixed effect and random effect in a model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, definition

I'm unconfident that whether my understanding on fixed effect and random effect is correct:

Fixed effect= variable that make inferences about the specific levels.

Random effect= variable that make inferences about and generalise to a wider population.

The aim for my model is to suggest the kind of videos to create on youtube so that they become popular and get large number of views.

I have 6 variables in my glm model:

1. Channel – YouTube account the video was uploaded from ( all account names, e.g.Netflix, star wars etc)
2. Views – Number of times the video was viewed ( that observed over unequal time interval)
3. Comments_disabled – Whether the channel disabled other users from commenting on the video (no = comments enabled, yes = comments disabled)
4. Theme – Category of the video (e.g. ‘Drama’, ‘Family’ etc)
5. Weeks – Number of weeks available on YouTube to date
6. Tags – Number of tags, key words assigned to the video that users can search for within YouTube

I defined them as:

Fixed effect: 2, 4, 5

Random effect: 1, 3, 6

I have categorized tags as random effect but I am not very certain about it.

And what is the main difference between a fixed effect model, a random effect model and a mixed model? From my understanding of these three models, fixed effect model = all variables are fixed effects, random effect model = all variables are random effects and mixed model = both fixed effects and random effects variables are in the model ?

Also, is it possible to get a glm model that only includes fixed effects?

I used the code below in glm

```
 glm( views ~ weeks, data = "youtube" , family = "poisson", link = "log")
```

and keep saying `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'`.

I'm not sure where I went wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I have figured out my code, it shall be `glm( views ~ weeks, data = "youtube" , family = "poisson" (link = "log"))`

Comment: This isn't really a question about fixed or random effects, and you aren't trying to estimate either a fixed- or random-effects model here.  But I'm guessing the problem is that you're specifying the data set as a string ("youtube") instead of a data frame object (youtube, presumably).

Comment: Thanks for mention the tags, i'm finding a mixed model in deed but I would also like to find out the difference between these 3 models ( I accidentally delected the question in my initial post and I've now added it back on).

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion was dead wrong.  Still, you're not fitting a mixed model.  It's just a (pooled) GLM with views as the dependent variable and weeks as the sole independent variable.  There are neither fixed nor random effects here.  Your questions about the differences between fixed effects models, random effects models, and mixed models are fair, but they are most likely already answered elsewhere, and they don't appear to be related to your error or the model you are estimating here.

Comment: I have not started to fit a mixed model yet because I am stucked on the very first step- I am unsure about my variables effects, whether they are fixed or random. Let me edit my question again for a better presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we include fixed and random effects, we call it a *mixed effects model* or often just a *mixed model*

From your description, it appears that only `channel` should be a random effect (random intercept)

`Comments_disabled` is a binary variable doesn't meet any reasonable criteria for fitting it as random. It should be a fixed effect.

`Tags` seems like a numeric variable and should be a fixed effect, though you might want to consider also fitting random slopes for it.

It's important to note that there are two types of random effects - random intercepts and random slopes. Random intercepts are for grouping variables, typically identifiers, and observations will be clustered within these. Within each cluster, you can allow fixed effects to vary, by specifying random slopes for those variables. It rarely makes sense to have a variable specified as a random slope without it also being a random intercept. So your mixed model could be something like:

```
views ~ Comments_disabled + Theme + Weeks + Tags + (1 | Channel), data = mydata
```

If you think that the effect, of, for example `Weeks` and `Tags` should vary by `Channel` then you can specify random slopes for them like this:

```
views ~ Comments_disabled + Theme + Weeks + Tags + (1 + Weeks + Tags | Channel), data = mydata
```

As for the question about `glm`, ignoring the clustering of observations in `Channel` this would lead to biased estimates, so you need to adjust for this, by, for example, fitting random intercepts for `Channel` with a mixed model. Also, although `Views` is a count (and potentially Poisson-distributed) if the counts are high then a normal distribution might be better. With count data, under- and over-dispersion can also be a problem.

As for the error, this is because of `data = "youtube"` 
(why to you  have `youtube` in double quotes ? - generally you want something like `data = mydata` where `mydata` is dataframe in R. Proabbly you should have `data = youtube` ). However please note that this is not a site for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm now trying to build up my GLMM model with r code: glm(views ~ comments_disabled + theme + weeks + tags + (1 | channel), data = youtube, family = "poisson"(link = "log")) but it comes up an error: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1, channel) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here. Also, you mentioned that numeric variables should classify as fixed effect, so it is wrong for me to have theme as fixed effect here as it is category of videos? ( even it is my aim to find out in my model?) @Robert Long

Comment: @BlackSky please put the output of `str(youtube)` into your question, and `summary(youtube)`.  Also I didn't understand the question in your last comment.

Comment: @BlackSky Wait, you wrote `glm(views ~ comments_disabled + theme + weeks + tags + (1 | channel)`  - is that what you did ? You can't use `glm` - it won't work -  you need to use a mixed effects function, such as `glmer` from the `lme4` package,